# Can the electrons be above the Fermi level(in a band gap)?

Tags: electronic-configuration

I've been searching this online for some time. It seems to be ignored most of the time but I found this on one website and I'm just trying to confirm it's true.

[image]

> Note that although the Fermi function has a finite value in the gap, there is no electron population at those energies (that's what you mean by a gap).

From the little I understood the Fermi function gives the probability to find an electron at a specific energy level. At temperature above 0 Kelvin f(E) is as shown above, meaning that there is a chance of finding an electron at an energy level in the gap. But then the website states that electrons can't occupy any state in the gap. If that is true the probability would be zero..

Comment: _"Occupy any state in the gap"_ is an oxymoron. There are no states in the gap.

Comment: Then why isn’t the probability zero ?

Comment: Probability does not care about states. It says something to the effect of _"if there were states with such-and-such energy, then their occupation would be..."_

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the Fermi function? Can we trust it for states in the conduction band, the valence band but not for the gap?

Comment: We can trust it for **any** states. It is just that there are no states in the gap.

Comment: Let's say that summing up the probabilities for energy states in the gap gives 1% probability. Then the probability of an electron being in the valence band would be 99%  instead of 100%(the gap 'steals' from it). Now,when trying to find the probability for a specific energy in the valence band I know that it doesn't reflect the real probability since that 1% steals from it.   Do we assume that this 1% is on the top of the valence band?

Comment: Summing up the probabilities for energy states in the gap gives precisely 0%, because the number of states in the gap is 0.

Comment: That should be the case but the function gives a number, that's what's troubling me. It is also stated in the quote I included " although the fermi function has a finite value in the gap"

Comment: So what if it gives a number? Don't use the said number, that's all.

Comment: If I make a dice with 5 sides instead of 6 each probability would be 1/5 not 1/6. Fermi is like using 1/6 for 5 sided dice. The results given for the gap are not just wrong, they also decrease the probability for the energies in the valence band, giving me wrong values as well ( 1/6 instead of the real 1/5).

Comment: My point is , if the numbers for the gap are not real then we can't trust the numbers for the valence gap either. The gap probabilities 'eat' from the others.

Comment: Then normalize the probabilities. You'd have to do it anyway, gap or no gap.

Comment: Actual occupancy at an energy is a convolution of the Fermi function with the density of states. No states, no occupancy. This is fundamental solid state physics.